# How to send an email to specific address on submit button press of contact form page in android app without invoking gmail app in contact form app?

Tags: android

I am making contact form for my app in which user will enter its name, mobile no, email id, and message along with it, user will choose a subject from spinner, after that when user click on Submit button the whole contact form information that user entered will send to my email id as67735@gmail.com without invoking gmail app in contact form app. How can I acheive this? I tried many blogs and tutorials to fulfill this task but in all places they described it by invoking gmail app in this contact form app but I want this functionality without invoking gmail app in my app. On pressing submit button a mail should be fired to my mail id.

Comment: is it important that the email will come from the user's email address? or will it be enough to have the user's email in the body of the email?

Comment: Of course you can send a silent email and without gmail app. Java mail.

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a , use these two links it will help to u.

Comment: @ greenapps its not for points.I don't want much points.Its enough for me.And for others,They will check answer checking with upvote and tick mark.Don't blame without knowing what is exact.